# Find all occurrences of substring in a vector and save results to another column

Tags: python

I have a data frame look like this:

```
data = {'ID':['DFSADFEFDSAE','FDSADFDSEFDSAFEFDSADFE','ESADFDSADFSADFSA']}
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to find all `'E'` in each string and save the indices into another column. I was trying with `re.finditer` and map to convert list to a string and save for each row but no luck yet. What would be a good approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
import re
data['new']=[[m.start() for m in re.finditer('E', i)] for i in data['ID']]
print(data)
```

Output:

```
                       ID          new
0            DFSADFEFDSAE      [6, 11]
1  FDSADFDSEFDSAFEFDSADFE  [8, 14, 21]
2        ESADFDSADFSADFSA          [0]
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method.

```
>>> data['matching_idx'] = data['ID'].apply(lambda x: [idx for idx, el in enumerate(x) if el == 'E'])
>>> data
                       ID        matching_idx
0            DFSADFEFDSAE      [6, 11]
1  FDSADFDSEFDSAFEFDSADFE  [8, 14, 21]
2        ESADFDSADFSADFSA          [0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using data frame, you can use classic Python collections, for instance:

```py
import collections

data = {'ID': ['DFSADFEFDSAE', 'FDSADFDSEFDSAFEFDSADFE', 'ESADFDSADFSADFSA']}

indexes = collections.defaultdict(list)
for letters in data['ID']:
    for index, letter in enumerate(letters):
        if letter == "E":
            indexes[letters].append(index)
print(indexes)
```

You get:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {
    'DFSADFEFDSAE': [6, 11],
    'FDSADFDSEFDSAFEFDSADFE': [8, 14, 21],
    'ESADFDSADFSADFSA': [0]
})
```